# Why I am not able to send an email using Amazon SES service?

Tags: c#, email, amazon-ses

I created a wd site, where a user1 can send email to user2.  My account is removed from the Amazon SES sandbox. You will find, my code bellow.
My  SMTP credentials are configured in US East (Ohio). But my location is in Canada. And the two emails that i am using are Canadian addresses (yahoo.ca)
I don’t understand why the User1 is not able to send an email to User2?
Here is my code:

```
 public void SendEmail(string sender, string recipient, string messageBODY)
    {
        // Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address. 
        // This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
        String FROM = sender;
        String FROMNAME = "Sender Name";

        // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
        // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
        String TO = recipient;

        // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
        String SMTP_USERNAME = "CAIASJA3JM5CXUEYAIAB";

        // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
        String SMTP_PASSWORD = "RD75K2MbhvOYnBf20WYZ5O9oZlj9lCBH/hqrEIYnClYT";

        // (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message.
        // If you comment out this line, you also need to remove or comment out
        // the "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET" header below.
        //String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

        // If you're using Amazon SES in a region other than US West (Oregon), 
        // replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP  
        // endpoint in the appropriate AWS Region.
        String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com";

        // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We
        // are choosing port 587 because we will use STARTTLS to encrypt
        // the connection.
        int PORT = 587;

        // The subject line of the email
        String SUBJECT =
            "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using C#)";

        // The body of the email
        String BODY = messageBODY;

        // Create and build a new MailMessage object
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.From = new MailAddress(FROM, FROMNAME);
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
        message.Subject = SUBJECT;
        message.Body = BODY;
        // Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
        //message.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

        using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
        {
            // Pass SMTP credentials
            client.Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

            // Enable SSL encryption
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            // Try to send the message. Show status in console.
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to send email...");
                client.Send(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for help

Comment: First you need to figure out if it's "not being sent" or "not being received". Do you get the "mail sent" or "mail not sent" message?

Comment: @TerryCarmen, I don't get either one!

Comment: @TerryCarmen, I don't get either one!  When I go in debug mode i get: Transaction failed. The server response was: Message rejected: Email address is not verified.

Comment: You need to find out which server is saying "email address not verified" and which address it's complaining about (sender or recipient)